# Why is the Python test debugger not stopping on a bug?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've just started using the tests functionality in the Python extension. I want to debug my test however when I hit the debug button in the tests extension the debugger runs but doesn't stop on a bug and display a red box with the error - it just reports a failed test in the debug console. This means I can't examine the variables that caused the error.

I've tried just running the normal debugger (not from within the tests section) on the test file but the same thing happens. I've tried the normal debugger on a non-test file and it works fine.

Is the test debugger supposed to work in the same way as the normal debugger, i.e. stop on a bug?

---

### Edit:

Worth me mentioning that the bug is occurring in the function I'm testing rather than the test file itself

---

### Edit_2:

I've tested break points and they seem to be working ok. Can't get a conditional one to work though

Comment: Apart from you question, using "Breakpoints" in testing is a good practice. It will helps in many ways to increase effectiveness of the testing process.

Let's look on your question. I think it is problem with the plugin/extension that you are using you have to report the particular developers. 

If you can please attach some codes and screenshots.

Comment: What screenshots would you like?

Comment: I think you have edited the question and mentioned about the breakpoints, awesome that is best practice. I was asking about your code and testing console screen.

Comment: I'd rather not get into producing an MRE if this is a simple question to answer. Are you able to tell me whether the debugger should stop on a bug when in the Python test extension?